# issue to place items in a navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem with the navbar. I would like the "register" button to be to the right of the "login" button, with a space of xxxpx from the right edge of the window, so that when you have the hover on the "login" button the form with the inputs does not appear off the screen. I tried to put the "register" button inside "" but due to the CSS code I get the login form even when there is hover on the "register" button and not is a desired behavior. How can I place the "register" button to the right of the "login" button?
P.S. This is code for anguar but does the same.
Thanks.

[image]

```css
.space {
  width: 350px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
}

.forminput {
  margin: 5px;
}

.formbutton {
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn-login {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content-login {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content-login a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn-login {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content-login a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content-login {
  display: block;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn-login {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .space {
    width: 0px;
  }
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content-login {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn-login {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a routerLink="/" class="active">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/gallery">Gallery</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn-login">Login</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-login">
      <form>
        <input class="forminput" placeholder="username">
        <input class="forminput" type="password" placeholder="password">
        <button class="formbutton" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a style="float:right" routerLink="/register">Register</a>
  <div style="float:right" class="space"></div>
  <a href="" class="icon" (click)="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place anchor tag for 'Register' button above the 'dropdown' div.

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
     <a routerLink="/" class="active">Home</a>
     <a routerLink="/gallery">Gallery</a>
  <a style="float:right" routerLink="/register">Register</a>
     <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="dropbtn-login">Login</button>
         <div class="dropdown-content-login">
             <form>
                <input class="forminput" placeholder="username">
                <input class="forminput" type="password" placeholder="password">
                <button class="formbutton" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right" class="space"></div>
    <a href="" class="icon" (click)="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. With your suggestion "register" button is on the right but miss the space I need to visualize "login" form.

Comment: Simply put '<br>' tag wherever you want a space.

Comment: I mean a orizzontal space from the right margin of the window, so that the login form can be displayed correctly

Comment: Try using padding or margin